# C++ Template Matrix Class - WIP

Tags: c++, matrix, template

I've created simple matrix class in c++ and I would like to know what you think about the code. I've left the implementation in header file for simplicity for now.

The class is not finished yet, it misses a lot of utilities, but wanted to get review of the basics.

```
#pragma once

#include <exception>
#include <vector>
#include <ostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template <class T>
class Matrix
{
public:
    // ************** BEGIN OF CONSTRUCTION / DESTRUCTION ************** //

    explicit Matrix(const size_t rowCount, const size_t columnCount, const bool initWithNull = true) :
        _rowCount{ rowCount },
        _columnCount{ columnCount }
    {
        if (_rowCount == 0)
        {
            throw Matrix_WrongRowCount{};
        }

        if (_columnCount == 0)
        {
            throw Matrix_WrongColumnCount{};
        }

        _data.resize(_rowCount * _columnCount);
        if (initWithNull)
        {
            auto it{ begin() };
            while (it != end())
            {
                *it++ = T{};
            }
        }
    }
    // Todo, other overloads of constructor, creating vector of vectors is not effective (new called for each row + 1 if the vector didnt exist yet)
    explicit Matrix(const std::vector<std::vector<T>>& arr) :
        _rowCount{ arr.size() },
        _columnCount{ 0 },
        _data{ std::vector<T>{} }
    {
        if (arr.size() == 0)
        {
            throw Matrix_ArrayIsEmpty{};
        }

        _columnCount = arr[0].size();
        const size_t dataCount{ _rowCount * _columnCount };

        for (const auto& row : arr)
        {
            if (row.size() != _columnCount)
            {
                throw Matrix_ArrayIsJagged{};
            }
        }

        _data.resize(dataCount);
        for (auto arrIt{ arr.begin() }, size_t row{ 0 }; arrIt != arr.end(); ++arrIt, ++row)
        {
            std::copy(arrIt->begin(), arrIt->end(), begin() + row * _columnCount);
        }
    }

    Matrix(const Matrix& other) :
        _rowCount{ other._rowCount },
        _columnCount{ other._columnCount },
        _data{ std::vector<T>{} }
    {
        _data.resize(_rowCount * _columnCount);
        std::copy(other.begin(), other.end(), _data.begin());
    }

    Matrix(Matrix&& other) :
        _rowCount{ other._rowCount },
        _columnCount{ other._columnCount },
        _data{ std::move(other._data) }
    {
        other._rowCount = other._columnCount = 0;
        other._data = std::vector<T>{};
    }

    virtual ~Matrix() = default;

    static Matrix CreateRowMatrix(const size_t columnCount)
    {
        return Matrix{ columnCount, 1 };
    }

    static Matrix CreateRowMatrix(const std::vector<T>& arr)
    {
        Matrix resultMatrix{ 1, arr.size(), false };
        std::copy(arr.begin(), arr.end(), resultMatrix.begin());

        return resultMatrix;
    }

    static Matrix CreateColumnMatrix(const size_t rowCount)
    {
        return Matrix{ rowCount, 1 };
    }

    static Matrix CreateColumnMatrix(const std::vector<T>& arr)
    {
        Matrix resultMatrix{ arr.size(), 1, false };
        std::copy(arr.begin(), arr.end(), resultMatrix.begin());

        return resultMatrix;
    }

    // todo, enable only for primitive type
    static Matrix CreateIdentityMatrix(const size_t size, const T value, bool rightToLeft = false)
    {
        Matrix resultMatrix{ size, size };
        for (size_t i{ 0 }; i < size; ++i)
        {
            resultMatrix(i, rightToLeft ? (size - i - 1) : i) = value;
        }

        return resultMatrix;
    }

    // for non primitive arithmetic types, pass by const reference
    // TODO: is it really useful? little optimization(not passing primitive type by reference) vs code bloat from template??? - same with multiplication by scalar
    // maybe remove the enableif and pass everything by const ref
    template<class U = T, typename std::enable_if<!std::is_arithmetic<U>::value>::type>
    static Matrix CreateIdentityMatrix(const size_t size, const T& value, bool rightToLeft = false)
    {
        Matrix resultMatrix{ size, size };
        for (size_t i{ 0 }; i < size; ++i)
        {
            resultMatrix(i, rightToLeft ? (size - i - 1) : i) = value;
        }

        return resultMatrix;
    }

    // ************** END OF CONSTRUCTION / DESTRUCTION ************** //
    // ************** BEGIN OF OPERATORS ************** //

    Matrix& operator=(const Matrix& other)
    {
        if (this != &other)
        {
            _rowCount = _columnCount = 0;
            _data.empty();
            _data.resize(other._data.size());

            std::copy(other.begin(), other.end(), _data.begin());
            _rowCount = other._rowCount;
            _columnCount = other._columnCount;
        }

        return *this;
    }

    Matrix& operator=(Matrix&& other)
    {
        if (this != &other)
        {
            _rowCount = other._rowCount;
            _columnCount = other._columnCount;
            _data = std::move(other._data);

            other._rowCount = other._columnCount = 0;
            other._data = std::vector<T>{};
        }

        return *this;
    }

    T& operator[](const size_t index) { return _data[index]; }
    const T& operator[](const size_t index) const { return _data[index]; }

    // substitution for double subscript[][]
    T& operator()(const size_t rowIndex, const size_t columnIndex) { return _data[index(rowIndex, columnIndex)]; }
    const T& operator()(const size_t rowIndex, const size_t columnIndex) const { return _data[index(rowIndex, columnIndex)]; }

    Matrix& operator+=(const Matrix& rightMatrix)
    {
        if (_rowCount != rightMatrix._rowCount)
        {
            throw Matrix_DifferentRowCount{};
        }
        else if (_columnCount != rightMatrix._columnCount)
        {
            throw Matrix_DifferentColumnCount{};
        }

        auto leftIt{ begin() };
        auto rightIt{ rightMatrix.begin() };
        while (leftIt != end())
        {
            *leftIt++ += *rightIt++;
        }

        return *this;
    }

    Matrix& operator-=(const Matrix& rightMatrix)
    {
        if (_rowCount != rightMatrix._rowCount)
        {
            throw Matrix_DifferentRowCount{};
        }
        else if (_columnCount != rightMatrix._columnCount)
        {
            throw Matrix_DifferentColumnCount{};
        }

        auto leftIt{ begin() };
        auto rightIt{ rightMatrix.begin() };
        while (leftIt != end())
        {
            *leftIt++ -= *rightIt++;
        }

        return *this;
    }

    // TODO: enableif U is primitive arithmetic type
    template<class U>
    Matrix& operator*=(const U scalar)
    {
        auto leftIt{ begin() };
        while (leftIt != end())
        {
            *leftIt++ *= scalar;
        }

        return *this;
    }

    template<class U = T, typename std::enable_if<!std::is_arithmetic<U>::value>::type>
    Matrix& operator*=(const U& scalar)
    {
        auto leftIt{ begin() };
        while (leftIt != end())
        {
            *leftIt++ *= scalar;
        }

        return *this;
    }

    Matrix operator*=(const Matrix& rightMatrix)
    {
        if (_columnCount != rightMatrix._rowCount)
        {
            throw Matrix_RowColumnMismatch{};
        }

        *this = std::move(*this * rightMatrix);

        return *this;
    }

    // ************** END OF OPERATORS ************** //
    // ************** BEGIN OF ACCESSORS ************** //

    auto begin() { return _data.begin(); }
    auto begin() const { return _data.begin(); }
    auto end() { return _data.end(); }
    auto end() const { return _data.end(); }

    size_t GetRowCount() const { return _rowCount; }
    size_t GetColumnCount() const { return _columnCount; }
    size_t GetDataCount() const { return _data.size(); }

    const size_t index(const size_t row, const size_t column) const { return row * _columnCount + column; }

    // ************** END OF ACCESSORS ************** //

    void SwapRows(const size_t row1, const size_t row2)
    {
        // todo: assert input

        // we can optimize this for rows, swap entire row in one run
        for (size_t column = 0; column < _columnCount; ++column)
        {
            std::swap((*this)(row1, column), (*this)(row2, column));
        }
    }

    void SwapColumns(const size_t column1, const size_t column2)
    {
        // todo: assert input

        for (size_t row = 0; row < _rowCount; ++row)
        {
            std::swap((*this)(row, column1), (*this)(row, column2));
        }
    }

    void RemoveRows(const size_t beginRow, const size_t amount = 1)
    {
        *this = std::move(RemoveRows(*this, beginRow, amount));
    }

    //void RemoveColumns(const size_t beginRow, const size_t amount = 1)
    //{
    //  *this = std::move(RemoveCols(*this, beginRow, amount));
    //}

    static Matrix Add(const Matrix& leftMatrix, const Matrix& rightMatrix) { return leftMatrix + rightMatrix; }
    static Matrix Subtract(const Matrix& leftMatrix, const Matrix& rightMatrix) { return leftMatrix - rightMatrix; }
    static Matrix Multiply(const Matrix& leftMatrix, const Matrix& rightMatrix) { return leftMatrix * rightMatrix; }

    static Matrix SwapRows(const Matrix& matrix, const size_t row1, const size_t row2)
    {
        Matrix resultMatrix{ matrix };
        resultMatrix.SwapRows(row1, row2);

        return resultMatrix;
    }

    static Matrix SwapColumns(const Matrix& matrix, const size_t column1, const size_t column2)
    {
        Matrix resultMatrix{ matrix };
        resultMatrix.SwapColumns(column1, column2);

        return resultMatrix;
    }

    static Matrix RemoveRows(const Matrix& matrix, const size_t beginRow, const size_t amount = 1)
    {
        // TODO: assert input

        Matrix resultMatrix{ matrix._rowCount - amount, matrix._columnCount, false };

        std::copy(matrix.begin(), matrix.begin() + beginRow * matrix._columnCount, resultMatrix.begin());
        std::copy(matrix.begin() + (beginRow + amount) * matrix._columnCount, matrix.end(), resultMatrix.begin() + beginRow * matrix._columnCount);

        return resultMatrix;
    }

    //static Matrix RemoveCols(const Matrix& matrix, const size_t beginRow, const size_t amount = 1)
    //{
    //  // TODO

    //  return Matrix<T>{1, 1};
    //}

    // todo: move outside of the class
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Matrix& matrix)
    {
        os << "\n";
        for (size_t index{ 0 }; index < matrix._data.size(); ++index)
        {
            if (index != 0 && index % matrix._columnCount == 0)
            {
                os << "\n";
            }

            os << matrix._data[index] << " ";
        }

        return os << "\n";
    }

protected:
    size_t _rowCount, _columnCount;
    std::vector<T> _data;
};

template<class T>
bool operator==(const Matrix<T>& leftMatrix, const Matrix<T>& rightMatrix)
{
    if (&leftMatrix == &rightMatrix)
    {
        return true;
    }

    if (leftMatrix.GetRowCount() != rightMatrix.GetRowCount() ||
        leftMatrix.GetColumnCount() != rightMatrix.GetColumnCount())
    {
        return false;
    }

    auto leftIt{ leftMatrix.begin() };
    auto rightIt{ rightMatrix.begin() };

    while (leftIt != leftMatrix.end())
    {
        if (*leftIt++ != *rightIt++)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

template<class T>
bool operator!=(const Matrix<T>& leftMatrix, const Matrix<T>& rightMatrix)
{
    return !(leftMatrix == rightMatrix); 
}


// TODO: remove the code and return += in here or leave it as it is, same with operator-
template<class T>
Matrix<T> operator+(const Matrix<T>& leftMatrix, const Matrix<T>& rightMatrix)
{
    if (leftMatrix.GetRowCount() != rightMatrix.GetRowCount())
    {
        throw Matrix_DifferentRowCount{};
    }
    else if (leftMatrix.GetColumnCount() != rightMatrix.GetColumnCount())
    {
        throw Matrix_DifferentColumnCount{};
    }

    auto resultMatrix{ Matrix<T>{leftMatrix.GetRowCount(), leftMatrix.GetColumnCount(), false } };
    auto resultIt{ resultMatrix.begin() };
    auto it1{ leftMatrix.begin() };
    auto it2{ rightMatrix.begin() };

    while (resultIt != resultMatrix.end())
    {
        *resultIt++ = *it1++ + *it2++;
    }

    return resultMatrix;
}

template<class T>
Matrix<T> operator-(const Matrix<T>& leftMatrix, const Matrix<T>& rightMatrix)
{
    if (leftMatrix.GetRowCount() != rightMatrix.GetRowCount())
    {
        throw Matrix_DifferentRowCount{};
    }
    else if (leftMatrix.GetColumnCount() != rightMatrix.GetColumnCount())
    {
        throw Matrix_DifferentColumnCount{};
    }

    auto resultMatrix{ Matrix<T>{leftMatrix.GetRowCount(), leftMatrix.GetColumnCount(), false } };
    auto resultIt{ resultMatrix.begin() };
    auto leftIt{ leftMatrix.begin() };
    auto rightIt{ rightMatrix.begin() };

    while (resultIt != resultMatrix.end())
    {
        *resultIt++ = *leftIt++ - *rightIt++;
    }

    return resultMatrix;
}

template<class T>
Matrix<T> operator-(const Matrix<T>& matrix)
{
    auto resultMatrix{ Matrix<T>{matrix.GetRowCount(), matrix.GetColumnCount(), false } };
    auto resultIt{ resultMatrix.begin() };
    auto matrixIt{ matrix.begin() };

    while (resultIt != resultMatrix.end())
    {
        *resultIt++ = -*matrixIt++;
    }

    return resultMatrix;
}

// TODO: enable only for primitive arithmetic types
template<class T, class U>
Matrix<T> operator*(const Matrix<T>& matrix, const U scalar)
{
    auto resultMatrix{ Matrix<T>{matrix.GetRowCount(), matrix.GetColumnCount(), false } };
    auto resultIt{ resultMatrix.begin() };
    auto matrixIt{ matrix.begin() };

    while (resultIt != resultMatrix.end())
    {
        *resultIt++ = *matrixIt++ * scalar;
    }

    return resultMatrix;
}

template<class T, typename std::enable_if<!std::is_arithmetic<T>::value>::type>
Matrix<T> operator*(const Matrix<T>& matrix, const T& scalar)
{
    auto resultMatrix{ Matrix<T>{matrix.GetRowCount(), matrix.GetColumnCount(), false } };
    auto resultIt{ resultMatrix.begin() };
    auto matrixIt{ matrix.begin() };

    while (resultIt != resultMatrix.end())
    {
        *resultIt++ = *matrixIt++ * scalar;
    }

    return resultMatrix;
}

template<class T>
Matrix<T> operator*(const Matrix<T>& leftMatrix, const Matrix<T>& rightMatrix)
{
    if (leftMatrix.GetColumnCount() != rightMatrix.GetRowCount())
    {
        throw Matrix_RowColumnMismatch{};
    }

    auto resultMatrix{ Matrix<T>{leftMatrix.GetRowCount(), rightMatrix.GetColumnCount(), false } };
    for (size_t row{ 0 }; row < resultMatrix.GetRowCount(); ++row)
    {
        for (size_t column{ 0 }; column < resultMatrix.GetColumnCount(); ++column)
        {
            for (size_t i{ 0 }; i < leftMatrix.GetColumnCount(); ++i)
            {
                resultMatrix(row, column) += leftMatrix(row, i) * rightMatrix(i, column);
            }
        }
    }

    return resultMatrix;
}

class Matrix_Exception : std::exception
{
public:
    Matrix_Exception(const char* msg) : std::exception(msg) {};
};

class Matrix_WrongRowCount : Matrix_Exception
{
public:
    Matrix_WrongRowCount() : Matrix_Exception("Row count should be at least 1") {}
};

class Matrix_WrongColumnCount : Matrix_Exception
{
public:
    Matrix_WrongColumnCount() : Matrix_Exception("Column count should be at least 1") {}
};

class Matrix_ArrayIsEmpty : Matrix_Exception
{
public:
    Matrix_ArrayIsEmpty() : Matrix_Exception("Array argument is empty") {}
};

class Matrix_ArrayIsJagged : Matrix_Exception
{
public:
    Matrix_ArrayIsJagged() : Matrix_Exception("Array argument is jagged") {}
};

class Matrix_DifferentRowCount : Matrix_Exception
{
public:
    Matrix_DifferentRowCount() : Matrix_Exception("Matrices have different row count") {}
};

class Matrix_DifferentColumnCount : Matrix_Exception
{
public:
    Matrix_DifferentColumnCount() : Matrix_Exception("Matrices have different column count") {}
};

class Matrix_RowColumnMismatch : Matrix_Exception
{
public:
    Matrix_RowColumnMismatch() : Matrix_Exception("Left column count is different than right row count") {}
};
```

Comment: I have just noticed, initWithNull in the very first constructor is a reprehensible error. Since std::vector::resize(size_type n, value_type val = value_type()) will automatically initialize the new elements, so when initWithNull is true, I am initializing it twice and the variable is without it's purpose. The error occured due to the fact, that I was previously using naked pointer and the memory was allocated by new, but was not initialized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assignment operators are not exception safe and thus you don't provide the strong exception guarantee.

```
Matrix& operator=(const Matrix& other)
{
    // Check for self assignment is a pessimization of the normal case.
    // Remember that self assignment is exceptionally rare, basically never
    // happens. BUT you should still handle the situation.
    if (this != &other)
    {
        // You delete your data before you know you can guarantee
        // the assignment works. You should not delete this data
        // until you know the assignment has worked.
        _rowCount = _columnCount = 0;
        _data.empty();
        _data.resize(other._data.size());


        // If T is an integer/float then this will never fail.
        //
        // But T can be anything so you can't guarantee this will
        // work. So you can't delete your old data until you
        // know the copy has worked.
        //
        // Now if you can lock this down so T is only int/float etc
        // this is totally fine.
        std::copy(other.begin(), other.end(), _data.begin());
        _rowCount = other._rowCount;
        _columnCount = other._columnCount;
    }

    return *this;
}
```

Personally I would rewrite this to use the Copy and Swap Idiom. That covers all your bases and is easier to write.

The move assignment works. But it is much simpler to write as a swap. Then you don't even need to check for self assignment.

```
Matrix& operator=(Matrix&& other)
{
    if (this != &other)
    {
        _rowCount = other._rowCount;
        _columnCount = other._columnCount;
        _data = std::move(other._data);

        other._rowCount = other._columnCount = 0;
        other._data = std::vector<T>{};
    }

    return *this;
}
```

Also note move semantics should be marked as `noexcept`. This allows optimizations when you put your matrix into a standard container. Note: Containers will only use move semantics for their members if the member has move semantics that are `noexcept`. This is because the standard tries very hard to provide the strong exception guarantee.

I would write them like this:

```
Matrix& operator=(Matrix const& other)
{
    Matrix  copy(other);
    copy.swap(*this);
    return *this;
}
Matrix& operator=(Matrix&& other) noexcept
{
    other.swap(*this);
    return *this;
}
```

#### Pass by Value does not need to be const

```
const T& operator()(const size_t rowIndex, const size_t columnIndex) const { return _data[index(rowIndex, columnIndex)]; }
                    ^^^^^ Does not buy you anything.
```

Comment: Thank you for your insight. Indeed I have forgot about the noexcept on the move semantics and didn't even think of doing a swap in move assigment. Const'ing pass by value parameters that shouldn't be changed in local scope is kinda my habit, if the value shouldn't be changed(even pass by value parameter) I just const it to prevent silly mistakes in bigger functions. I have done the necessary changes and I hope I won't make such mistakes in the future. Have a nice day.

Comment: I'm in two minds whether to comment on your statement "*[Pass] by Value does not need to be `const`*".  It doesn't need to be, and it serves no purpose in a pure *declaration*, but this is also the *definition*, and I sometimes find that const parameters can ease understanding of the implementation.  There's nothing to stop you using `const` in the definition, but omitting it in the declarations you provide in a header file, and that's actually what I often do.